# How to get file location of currently open program?

Tags: gaming, windows-11

I want to know if there is a way to get the file location of a exe/program that is currently running? I have an exe file for a game and the location of the exe I cannot find. Any way to do this? Btw I’m using windows 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can view this information in the Task Manager (Ctrl+Alt+Delete => Task Manager). If you right-click on one of the processes (some have the properties option, some don't; choose either the top-level entry or one of its sub-entries) and view properties, it will show you the Location of the exe:

[image]

In this case, `KeePass.exe` is at `C:\Program Files\KeePass Password Safe 2\`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps me a lot